# CORS issue Angular 8 / Java Spring

Tags: angular, spring, api, request, cors

I have a big issue since many hours.
I make an Angular app with a Java Spring API.
All my POST/GET/DELETE request are OK. But one is falling, POST "/login", witch need to send an FormData ( I don't decide it, it's the Spring security's default format.)

I have this error :
[browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3UbQ.png)

[image]

This is my Angular request :
[angular request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws4ke.png)

[image]

This is my Spring Security Config :
[spring security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBhK1.png)

[image]

This is my CORS config in Spring :
[spring cors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZXe4.png)

[image]

Any one has an idea ? ;)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue

Angular request header just need "Content-type":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF8ej.png)

and Spring CORS like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XNEF.png)

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Try to test your options request on postman on the /login endpoint. Also, check if the "Access-control-allow-origin" header is present on the response of the server. The CORS issue cannot be resolved on the client, only on the server.

Comment: Cool. Good luck on the next ones!